# Given that $z=2-i$ and $z^2=3-4i$ find the roots of the equation $(z+i)^2=3-4i$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Given that $z=2-i$ and $z^2=3-4i$ find the roots of the equation $(z+i)^2=3-4i$

How do you use the given properties to find the roots? I can only obtain them the long way by working through

$$\begin{align}
&(z+i)(z+i)&=3-4i\\
&z^2+2zi+i^2&=3-4i\\
&z^2+2zi-1-3+4i&=0\\
&z^2+2zi+4i-4&=0\\
&z^2+2z-2z+2iz+4i-4&=0\\
&(z-(2-2i))(z+2)&=0\\ 
\end{align}$$
$$z=2-2i, z=-2$$

Comment: But if you already *know* that $z=2-i$, then how can $(z+i)^2=3-4i$??

Comment: I agree; I don't understand the statement of the problem.

Comment: He’s using “$z$” as both constant and indeterminate. Bad form. He should have asked for the roots of $(X+i)^2=3-4i$.

Comment: What I think is meant is that, given $(2 - i)^2 = 3 - 4i$, find the roots of $(z + i)^2 = 3 - 4i$.

Comment: @Gez Bishop : your question makes no sense because you wrote $z = 2- i$.  What is there to solve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align*}
(z+i)^2 &= 3 -4i\\
(z + i)^2 &= (2 -i)^2\\
(z+i)^2 - (2-i)^2 &= 0\\ 
[(z+i) - (2-i)][(z+i) + (2-i)] &= 0\\
[z - (2 - 2i)][z - 2] &= 0
\end{align*}

Therefore $z = 2 -2i$ or $z = 2$.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can find one root: $z+i=2-i$, so $z_1=2-2i$.
You can also get from the coefficients that $z_1+z_2=-2i$, then $z_2=-2$.

You can refer to [Vieta's formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viete_theorem).